# Install private package in a github action

Tags: npm, github-actions, github-package-registry

I am working with some private packages hosted on github.
In my workflow I have this:

```
 - name: Set GitHub packages registry
        run: |
          echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" > ~/.npmrc

      - name: Install Node.js dependencies
        run: yarn
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
```

But the build keeps failing with 401 unauthorized. I also have this setup in a step before:

```
- name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.13.0
          registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/
```

Any idea what is wrong here? The package is downloaded correctly locally because I have a .npmrc file with this code:

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken={mytoken}
```

Comment: I have also set the permissions to write-all yet nothing, still cannot fetch the package

Answer (score 1):

this solves the install dependency issue

```
uses: actions/setup-node@v1
    with:
      node-version: 18
      registry-url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
      # Defaults to the user or organization that owns the workflow file
      scope: '@YOUR_SCOPE'
  - name: Install dependencies
    run: npm ci
    env:
      NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_PACKAGE_SECRET }}
  - run: npm run build
  - run: npm publish
    env:
      NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_PACKAGE_SECRET }}
```

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution, so for other people having the same issue.
I needed to give access to the repo inside the package settings. So if I want to download package A in to package B I need to go to Package A settings and give access to package B.

Comment: Nice to provided us future solution seekers with your solution. But how and were did you have to change what to make this happen? Did you change anything in your package.json?

Comment: Was the `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN` env var still required?